# bourne shell single-quote, doublequote & backquote question

Tags: shell, sh

## /!bin/sh

```
   if [ "`echo $desc $status | awk -F"," '{print $3}' | awk -F" " '{print $1}' | sed '/^$/d'`" != "OK" ]; then
        echo "howdy dody"
   fi

echo $desc $status | awk -F"," '{print $3}' | awk -F" " '{print $1}' | sed '/^$/d'
```

First if-condition won't run, im guessing it's because of improper quotation, but i can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what is $desc and $status supposed to be ?? Your commands can be simplified further!!

Comment: It probably can, but that's not an issue.

Comment: so what is $desc and $status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Bash, I'd recommend `$(...)` instead of back-quotes. What error messages do you get? My guess is that the `-F","` option to awk is not being quoted properly. Trying inserting `\` to escape the quotation marks.

Comment: Sorry, can't use $(...) very very old shell. MMm, good suggestion, gonna try that.

Comment: can't use $()?? then why the bash tag?

Comment: Was simply a matter of escaping. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Update the tags as well, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use single quotes around the argument to the `-F` option as you have around other arguments:

```
if [ "`echo $desc $status | awk -F',' '{print $3}' | awk -F' ' '{print $1}' | sed '/^$/d'`" != "OK" ]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to write your test if you wrap it in a function:

```
mytest()
{
  echo "$1 $2" \
  | awk -F"," -v arg3="$3" '{print arg3}' \
  | awk -F" " -v arg1="$1" '{print arg1}' \
  | sed '/^$/d'
}
```

This way, you can verify that it works correctly. Once you gained this confidence

```
if [ "$(mytest "$desc" "$status")" != "OK" ]; then
        echo "howdy doody"
fi
```

or

```
if mytest "$desc" "$status" | grep -q -v '^OK$'; then
  echo "howdy doody"
fi
```

Comment: might as well pass $desc and $status as parameters to the function

Comment: Good point, I generalized the function as suggested. (Hoped my laziness would remain unnoticed.)

Comment: Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, you might want to try escaping some of the double quotes:

```
   if [ "`echo $desc $status | awk -F"," '{print $3}' | awk -F" " '{print $1}' | sed '/^$/d'`" != "OK" ]; then
        echo "howdy dody"
   fi
```

to

```
   if [ "`echo $desc $status | awk -F\",\" '{print $3}' | awk -F\" \" '{print $1}' | sed '/^$/d'`" != "OK" ]; then
        echo "howdy doody"
   fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the double quotes is certainly a good idea, but it looks like the $3 and the $1 are intended to be interpreted by awk.  They are being interpreted by your shell instead.  You probably want to escape the '$'s.  (It is possible that you have meaningful values for $1 and $3 in the shell, but not likely.)

Comment: No, they're in single quotes so they don't need escaping.

Comment: The backticks (should, don't know what shell this is) execute the pipeline in a subshell, so the "inner" double quotes are not effected by the "outer" double quotes